# wordpress mu sub-site image url

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress multisite + domain mapping with one main and two child website. I have setup threewp broadcast to share products to childsites.

Everything works so far but when displaying products on the childsite the image path is the mainsite with a 403 (Forbidden) I have used the below code in my themes `function.php` to make the main and the child sites share uploads paths. Is that the best way to do it? I'm trying to get all the child site product image paths to be the same as childsite domain. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
// Define a single common image directory for your Multisite
add_filter('upload_dir', 'mu_media_upload_dir');
function mu_media_upload_dir($upload) {
  global $user_ID;
  if ((int)$user_ID > 0) {
    $upload['path'] = ABSPATH . 'uploads/images';
    switch_to_blog(1);
    $upload['url'] = site_url() . '/' . 'uploads/images';
    restore_current_blog();
    $upload['subdir'] = "";
    $upload['basedir'] = $upload['path'];
    $upload['baseurl'] = $upload['url'];
  }
  return $upload;
}
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/

Comment: with or without the code it doesn't work

Comment: Please delete this question